# Biblatex: Is it possible to use a literal data annotation as a bibstring?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use literal data annotations as localization keys. Some use cases include: embellishing items in a list of ISBNs with the relevant type, e.g. "hardcover" or "ebook"; and (selectively) specifying locations, e.g. "Some Publisher: Amherst, MA" but "University of Massachusetts: Amherst". I have not been able to figure out how to get this to work; see my MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @book{foo,
    author = {John Shade and Charles Kinbote},
    author+an = {2:family="commentator"},
    date = {2000-01-01},
    date+an = {="prepublished"},
    title = {The Title},
    title+an = {="fromenglish"},
    location = {Cambridge},
    location+an = {1="countryus"},
  }
\end{filecontents}

% Can't use part annotation as bibstring:
%\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{ \bibxstring{\getpartannotation{family}}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{ {\getpartannotation{family}}}{}{}

% Can't use item annotation as bibstring:
%\xapptolistformat{location}{ \bibxstring{\getitemannotation}}{}{}
\xapptolistformat{location}{ {\getitemannotation}}{}{}

% Can't use field annotation as bibstring:
%\xapptofieldformat{titlecase}{ \bibxstring{{\getfieldannotation}}}{}{}
\xapptofieldformat{titlecase}{ {\getfieldannotation}}{}{}

% Same with date fields:
%\xapptobibmacro{date+extradate}{ \bibxstring{\getfieldannotation[date]}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extradate}{ {\getfieldannotation[date]}}{}{}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This code compiles, and successfully prints the literal annotations in the expected places. If I replace one of the uncommented `xappto` lines with its commented-out variant, I get a `Missing \endcsname` error; the annotation is printed in boldface as if the corresponding localization string were undefined. Replacing `\bibxstring` with `\bibstring` fails even more catastrophically.

I can work around this by putting `\bibstring` macros directly into the data annotations in the `.bib` file, but I find this slightly ugly and wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macros to retrieve data annotation are generally not expandable, because they work with optional arguments. That means they cannot be used as argument of `\bibxstring` (and definitely not as argument to `\bibstring`).

We can try and define new commands (without optional arguments) that retrieve the data expandably.

I've come up with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,%
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*{\expandablefieldannotation}[1]{%
  \expandablefieldannotationmanual{#1}{}}

\newcommand*{\expandablefieldannotationmanual}[2]{%
  \csuse{abx@annotation@literal@field@%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\currentfield}{#1}@%
    \ifstrempty{#2}{default}{#2}}}

\newcommand*{\expandableitemannotation}[1]{%
  \expandableitemannotationmanual{#1}{}{}}

\newcommand*{\expandableitemannotationmanual}[3]{%
  \csuse{abx@annotation@literal@item@%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\currentlist}{#1}@%
    \ifstrempty{#2}{default}{#2}@%
    \ifstrempty{#3}{\the\value{listcount}}{#3}}}

\newcommand*{\expandablepartannotation}[2]{%
  \expandablepartannotationmanual{#1}{}{}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\expandablepartannotationmanual}[4]{%
  \csuse{abx@annotation@literal@part@%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\currentname}{#1}@%
    \ifstrempty{#2}{default}{#2}@%
    \ifstrempty{#3}{\the\value{listcount}}{#3}@#4}}

% Can't use part annotation as bibstring:
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{ \bibxstring{\expandablepartannotation{}{family}}}{}{}

% Can't use item annotation as bibstring:
\xapptolistformat{location}{ \bibxstring{\expandableitemannotation{}} }{}{}

% Can't use field annotation as bibstring:
\xapptofieldformat{titlecase}{ \bibxstring{\expandablefieldannotation{}}}{}{}

% Same with date fields:
\xapptobibmacro{date+extradate}{ \bibxstring{\expandablefieldannotation{date}}}{}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{foo,
  author      = {John Shade and Charles Kinbote},
  author+an   = {2:family="commentator"},
  date        = {2000-01-01},
  date+an     = {="prepublished"},
  title       = {The Title},
  title+an    = {="fromenglish"},
  location    = {Cambridge},
  location+an = {1="countryus"},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

for now, but the interface could be improved.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!